# Who should I submit a bug to when two vendor libraries collide?

Tags: open-source, libraries, third-party-libraries, bug-report, standard-library

I found a bug. Yay for me.

The bug is such a mix of technologies I am not sure who I should submit the bug to.

The bug is a mix of Adobe Experience Manager and Angular Materials. Neither is really at fault. It has to do with some very clever javascript inside of AEM and the use of Internet Explorer Media Query hacks that are used inside of Angular Materials.

It may even be the browsers at fault.

For those not aware of the Internet Explorer media query hack, it involves writing a media query like this:

`@media screen\0`

The real problem is that this creates an invalid character in the DOM's CSS rule property. You can see it on this CodePen if your really interested, just look at the console of your browser.

http://codepen.io/TylersDesk/pen/gPzZwJ

Proprietary javascript inside of AEM can be hacked to work and check for the invalid character and it fixes the issue, but then I am modifying code I shouldn't and breaking upgrade paths.

Angular Materials is using this Media Query Hack in their production codebase, but it is a pretty mainstream hack from what I can tell.

When two libraries collide in such a strange way, with no body truly at fault, who do I submit my bug to?

Comment: You should report it to them all. But as you say, your particular use case may be unsupported

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular Materials is in violation of the CSS specification ("@media" must be followed by one or more identifiers, which may not contain null, separated by commas and whitespace, which also may not contain null, followed by an open brace), and as such no other vendor has any obligation whatsoever to support it. As such, your only recourse is to either report it to the angular developers, or fix it yourself. The latter is likely to be much more productive.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. With something as progressive as Angular Materials I am doubtful they will be doing anything to fix this, but I will report it anyway and have opened a discussion in their form to determine if they are going to address it.